# CSS Font Sizing - Using "/"

Tags: css, fonts

I've seen sites with `font-size:12px/2em` (or similar) specified on the body.

What does this font sizing do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shorthand for setting the font-size (12px) and the line-height (2em). Though, I didn't think you could do it on the `font-size` property, only on the `font` property.

Answer (score 2):

12px is the font size and 2em is the line-height.