# Why are there 2 font sizes in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Font Sizing - Using “/”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491172/css-font-sizing-using)

What does it mean when there are 2 font sizes in css

ex.

```
font: 14px/18px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First part is `font-size`. Second part is `line-height`.

Comment: I was about to post the same. +1

Answer (score 5):

It's a CSS 'Shorthand property' for `font size` and `line height`, `font-size: 14px;` and `line-height: 18px;`

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for font in css has the form:

font: *font-sytle font-weight font-size/line-height font-family*

your css code is equivallently to these three:

```
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 18px;
```

Comment: yes, thank you. it is a foolish type mistake.